# Install of drupal/core failed

Tags: installation, composer

my installation:  > drupal > lando composer install :ended up as seen below, I have run out of ideas what to do with this.

117/118 [===========================>]  99%    Install of drupal/core failed

In Filesystem.php line 318:

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /app/vendor/composer/9b30b0b4/drupal-core-1272c35/modules/**block/tests/modules**:

Can anybody help?
Thank you

ANSWER TO – leymannx : I did remove it but it doesn't help anything

I have reinstalled it again and it endded up the same except for the file is different.

- Installing mexitek/phpcolors (v1.0.4): Extracting archive
  117/118 [===========================>]  99%    Install of drupal/core failed

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /app/vendor/composer/9e14d34d/drupal-core-1272c35/modules/**config_translation**:

that's strange really

ANSWER TO – Sssweat: I run windows and the `chmod ug+w -R vendor/composer` command doesn't work in my enviroment, neither in cmd nor VScode terminal.

I tried `icacls vendor\composer /grant BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)F` which is suppose do the same thing but it had no positive effect.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!! What happens when you manually `rm -rf /app/vendor/composer/9b30b0b4/drupal-core-1272c35/modules/block/tests/modules`? You tried that already? Please update your question. Please don't try to clarify in comments. Thank you

Comment: From root folder try `chmod ug+w -R vendor/composer` and then `lando composer install`